# how can I create a tcolorbox with line numbering?

Tags: tcolorbox, line-numbering

I created the following tcolorbox:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lineno}


\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[middle=0mm,boxsep=0mm]
Headers

\tcblower

\setlength\linenumbersep{-.1cm} %sets the distance of the line numbers from the margin
\setcounter{linenumber}{1}
\begin{internallinenumbers}

\begin{itemize}
\item bullet 1
\item bullet 2
\item bullet 3
\begin{equation}
a = b,
\end{equation}
\noindent where $a$ and $b$ are...
\end{itemize}

\end{internallinenumbers}

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

However, as you can see, the line numbers on the left margin are not showing well. I would like not to number empty lines (but only number the bullet points and equation). Is there a way to make the line number more reasonable?

Comment: The main cause for this is `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`

Comment: So what if I want equations in the line numbering environment?

Comment: if it helps, I will be happy if equations are even not numbered at all, and ignored, but can appear in the internallinenumbers environment.

Comment: If you are willing to use `\tcbhighmath{a=b}` it works (you can change the style of `\tcbhighmath` with `highlight math style={...}`

Comment: it doesn't seem to work for me with \tcbhighmath -- there are still empty lines marked with numbers, and the numbers are not quite aligned with the equation.

Comment: Well, I can't help here -- I don't see the point in using line numbers unless you want to document code itself with LaTeX

Answer (score 2):

Based on a comment made by the OP, "*if it helps, I will be happy if equations are even not numbered at all*", one can resolve the issue by placing the math as inline, feigning displaymath with paragraph offsets and `\hfil`s.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lineno}


\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[middle=0mm,boxsep=0mm]
Headers

\tcblower

\setlength\linenumbersep{-.1cm} %sets the distance of the line numbers from the margin
\setcounter{linenumber}{1}
\begin{internallinenumbers}

\begin{itemize}
\item bullet 1
\item bullet 2
\item bullet 3

\hfil$%\begin{equation}
a = b,
$\hfil%\end{equation}

\noindent where $a$ and $b$ are...
\end{itemize}

\end{internallinenumbers}

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]