# Line numbers in tcolorbox, "notebook"/answer lines style

Tags: tcolorbox, line-numbering

I wanted to adapt the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504779/9424) to insert line numbers on the left side (inside the box) -- just like listings in the `tcolorbox` package.

I have also tried to put an optional number of lines argument in the `newtcolorbox` command, but as it didn't work, it ended up with the shoddy manual `vspace` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{calc}

\newtcolorbox{notebook}{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colback=green!10,
    colframe=green!65!black,
    left=.7in,
    underlay={%
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
        %\shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
%(interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines, ystep=\baselineskip, xstep=\linewidth, 
            shift={(interior.north west)}](interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \draw[help lines] ([xshift=.5in]interior.north west)--
            ([xshift=.5in]interior.south west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}}
    }

\usepackage{lineno}


\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{notebook}
\blindtext[3]
\end{notebook}

\begin{notebook}
\vspace{20\baselineskip}
\linenumbers
\end{notebook}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Probably I misunderstand your question, but you can just add an optional parameter that inserts the empty lines using `before upper`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{calc}

\newtcolorbox{notebook}[1][0]{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colback=green!10,
    colframe=green!65!black,
    left=.7in,
    underlay={%
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
        %\shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
%(interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines, ystep=\baselineskip, xstep=\linewidth, 
            shift={(interior.north west)}](interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \draw[help lines] ([xshift=.5in]interior.north west)--
            ([xshift=.5in]interior.south west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    before upper=\vspace{#1\baselineskip}   
    }

\usepackage{lineno}


\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{notebook}
\blindtext[3]
\end{notebook}

\begin{notebook}[20]

\end{notebook}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: As for your additional request: here is something along those lines (partly inspired by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/291617)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{calc}

\newtcolorbox{notebook}[1][0]{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colback=green!10,
    colframe=green!65!black,
    left=.7in,
    underlay={%
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
        %\shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
%(interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines, ystep=\baselineskip, xstep=\linewidth, 
            shift={(interior.north west)}](interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \draw[help lines] ([xshift=.5in]interior.north west)--
            ([xshift=.5in]interior.south west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    before upper={\ifnum#1>0
    \begin{internallinenumbers}\setcounter{linenumber}{1}
    \foreach \X in {1,...,#1}
    {~\par}
    \end{internallinenumbers}
    \fi
    }}

\usepackage{lineno}


\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{notebook}
\blindtext[3]
\end{notebook}

\begin{notebook}[20]
\end{notebook}

\begin{notebook}[20]
\end{notebook}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's part of the question -- the other part is numbering each line of the box.

Comment: @Joseph I added something. (To be honest, the line numbering part is not too obvious to me from the question.)

Comment: That's great! But the weird thing is, if any text is added inside the box, it goes _after_ the last number... (maybe because of `before upper`). But anyways, that's enough for me at the moment...